# How to include below subquery in a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
with cte as
(
    select trd_nbr,[date],sum(case when txn_typ='A' then abs(amount) else 0 end) 
     amountforA,
    sum(case when txn_typ='B' then abs(amount) else 0 end) amountforB, 
    sum(case when txn_typ='C' then abs(amount) else 0 end) amountforC
    from table1
    group by trd_nbr,[date]
)
select 
    trd_nbr,[date], 
    (case when amountforA=amountforB and amountforB=amountforC then amountforC 
    else amountforA-amountforC end) Amount,
     (case when amountforA=amountforB and amountforB=amountforC then 'M' else 
      'NM' end) Matched
from 
    cte 
where
    amountforA > 0 and amountforB > 0 and amountforC > 0
```

How to use this query in a stored procedure?

```
 create proc proc name()
    begin 
    select amount, matched ,...from table1 
  where condition.. 
union all 
select column1, column2.... from table2
    where condition.. 
    end;
```

Here amount and matched column are taking from with clause. How to use it?

Comment: For both scenario you mention `same logic for C and B`. Can you show some example with `C and B` ? Please also show your attempt

Comment: yes, If records common columns and sum amount for B and C are matched then display c alone. if not matched then B-C.

Comment: Scenario 1 output:

C amount = 4000 with single row display for trade number 1

Scenario 2 output:

C amount = 10000-5000 = 5000 with single row for trade number 2

C amount = 6000-2000 = 4000 with single row for trade number 3

Answer (score 2):

If the transaction types are fixed then it can be easily achieved using `pivot`. Please try the following:

```
drop table if exists #temp
select *
into #temp
from
(
    select trd_nbr, txn_typ, sum(abs(amount)) total
    from tab t
    group by trd_nbr, txn_typ
)t
pivot 
(
    sum(total) for txn_typ in ([A], [B], [C])
)pvt

select trd_nbr, case when C=A then C else A-C end as Final_C_amount
from #temp
```

You can check for B and C as well.

Please find the db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=6fa599cc4c9d724a5941a25739c8e88f).

Comment: when i implement in DB. I got wrong records. here we are getting matched and unmatched based on only sum of amount columns. we need to match other common columns like trade_nbr, date with sum of amount of A with  common columns of C like trade_nbr, date with sum of amount of C . we can filter records based on this condition. for both matched and unmatched.. we need to add common columns with sum of amount columns in both matched and unmatched condition .. could you implement this logic in same sql

Comment: @RagavendraDevraj sorry for the delayed response, could you please provide the exact output (db<>fiddle link) you need as it's not very clear to me from your note? do you need all the records of the base table with Amount and Matched column added to it?