# How to use with clause CTE expression in stored procedure select clause common

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
with cte as
(
    select trd_nbr,[date],sum(case when txn_typ='A' then abs(amount) else 0 end) 
     amountforA,
    sum(case when txn_typ='B' then abs(amount) else 0 end) amountforB, 
    sum(case when txn_typ='C' then abs(amount) else 0 end) amountforC
    from table1
    group by trd_nbr,[date]
     )
    select trd_nbr,[date], 
      (case when amountforA=amountforB and amountforB=amountforC then amountforC 
    else amountforA-amountforC end) Amount,
     (case when amountforA=amountforB and amountforB=amountforC then 'M' else 
      'NM' end) Matched
      from cte WHERE amountforA>0 and amountforB>0 and amountforC>0
```

How to use above query in a stored procedure?

```
create proc proc name()
    begin 
    select amount, matched ,...from table1 
  where condition.. 
union all 
select column1, column2.... from table2
    where condition.. 
    end;
```

Here amount and matched column are taking from with clause. how to use it..

Comment: What is wrong with the answer in your [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66962409/need-to-write-both-the-scenario-in-where-clause-to-filter-the-rows-returning) ?

Comment: Wha'ts your desired output? trd_nbr|date  |amount|     |:----:|:----:|:----     |1      |2/5/21| 4000 |2    |8/12/21 |5000  ?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure whether I understood you correctly or not. If it's not what you are looking for then please share your desired output in single table.

Schema and insert statement:

```
 create table table1(trd_nbr int, date date,amount int, txn_typ varchar(10));
 insert into table1 values(1,   '2/5/21',   4000,   'A');
 insert into table1 values(1,   '2/5/21',   -4000,  'B');
 insert into table1 values(1,   '2/5/21',   2000,   'C');
 insert into table1 values(1,   '2/5/21',   2000,   'C');
 insert into table1 values(2,   '8/12/21',  10000,  'A');
 insert into table1 values(2,   '8/12/21',  -5000,  'B');
 insert into table1 values(2,   '8/12/21',  5000,   'C');

 insert into table1 values(1 ,'2/5/21',4000 ,'A'  ); 
 insert into table1 values(2 ,'5/3/21',-3000 ,'B' );  
 insert into table1 values(4 ,'2/5/21', 2000 ,'Z' );
 GO
```

Query#1 (using common table expression)

```
 with cte as
 (
     select trd_nbr,[date],sum(case when txn_typ='A' then abs(amount) else 0 end) amountforA,
     sum(case when txn_typ='B' then abs(amount) else 0 end) amountforB, 
     sum(case when txn_typ='C' then abs(amount) else 0 end) amountforC
     from table1
     group by trd_nbr,[date]
 )
 select trd_nbr,[date], 
 (case when amountforA=amountforB and amountforB=amountforC then amountforC else amountforA-amountforC end) Amount,
 (case when amountforA=amountforB and amountforB=amountforC then 'M' else 'NM' end) Matched
 from cte WHERE amountforA0 and amountforB0 and amountforC0
```

Output:

| trd_nbr | date | Amount | Matched |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-02-05 | 4000 | NM |
| 2 | 2021-08-12 | 5000 | NM |

Query#2 (using subquery)

```
 select trd_nbr,[date], *,
 (case when amountforA=amountforB and amountforB=amountforC then amountforC else amountforA-amountforC end) Amount,
 (case when amountforA=amountforB and amountforB=amountforC then 'M' else 'NM' end) Matched
 from 
 (
     select trd_nbr,[date],sum(case when txn_typ='A' then abs(amount) else 0 end) amountforA,
     sum(case when txn_typ='B' then abs(amount) else 0 end) amountforB, 
     sum(case when txn_typ='C' then abs(amount) else 0 end) amountforC
     from table1
     group by trd_nbr,[date]
 )t
 WHERE amountforA0 and amountforB0 and amountforC0
```

Output:

| trd_nbr | date | Amount | Matched |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-02-05 | 4000 | NM |
| 2 | 2021-08-12 | 5000 | NM |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1982f1f8e18c2d36b1469aab5601bf6b)*

Comment: Actually i want to implement this in store proc  where clause... filter condition.. is it possible to create flag like for matched records 'M' and not matched records ' NM ' ..

Comment: It works like charm from SQL server 2005. You might having problem to join this query with other part of your query. I have also revised my answer by using subquery instead of common table expression.

Comment: You are most welcome. then please accept tjis answer.

Comment: when i implement in DB. I got wrong records. here we are getting matched and unmatched based on only sum of amount columns. we need to match other common columns like trade_nbr, date with sum of amount  of A with common columns like trade_nbr, date with sum of amount  of A with common columns  of C like trade_nbr, date with sum of amount  of C . we can filter records based on this condition. for both matched and unmatched.. we need to add common columns with sum of amount columns in both matched and unmatched condition .. could you implement this logic in same sql

Comment: I can give it a try. Please share some sample data with desired output for which this query is failing.

Comment: DB has only A record, no B and C. only B no C. something like that and Even NOT A, B , C which has zero amount also prsent in it, so we are checking with amount column only so it is matching with zero records as well and give as matched records. and only A or Only B gives as not matched records. but we want matched and unmatched shold happen on A , B, C

Comment: |trd_nbr|date  |amount|txn_typ|
        |:----:|:----:|:----:|:-----:|
        |1     |2/5/21|4000  |'A'   |
        |2    |5/3/21|-3000 |'B'   |
        |4    |2/5/21| 2000  |'Z'   |

Comment: you want a output row only when there are rows with A, B and C for a trd_nbr and date? Right? Can amount column be zero (0) for A, B or C?

Comment: yes, out put row only. but common column shoud include for matching only sum amount is same or different for match and un match column but common column is like filter to reach particular trade number with A,B and C. otherwise it goes to single A alone trade or B alone trade, and sum amount zero for different transactions are considerred. but  i don't want that  sum zero with different transaction and single transaction only A only B scenario

Comment: Please check my revised answer.

Comment: WHERE amountforA0 and amountforB0 and amountforC0 ? could you tell me what is referencing

Comment: i didnot see the common columns are taken for matching .

Comment: Didn't understand properly. Please elaborate a little bit.

Comment: i want column 1, column 2 , sum amount of A from table 1 where txn typ = A  should match with column 1 column 2  sum amount of C from table 1 where txn type = C

Comment: That's what it's doing. It's comparing sum of A with sum of C with same trd_nbr and date. `group by trd_nbr,[date]` is used to do so.

Comment: ok. i will check. if i want to include in store proc. how to modify  this query. flag details in one column of selct clause and remaining condition in immediately below or where clause of proc.

Comment: @KaziMohammadAliNur . could you help me to apply this query in store proc. i need to use flag in one of the column of select clause.

Comment: I would try. Please share your stored procedure's code.

Comment: i added store proc query in the question . please check

Comment: did you try this query into store procedure ?